# Setting Enum property in Editor Part dynamically

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part

I have a custom web part in SharePoint 2010. It has a content editor part implemented.Content Editor part has following properties say Choice : choice1,choice2.....choice5 these are checkboxes. Choice is a enum and checkbox collection has been created from this enum that is displayed in editor part.

I am trying to access this web part in an another project and trying to set the "Choice" check boxes but not sure how to do that. Where "Choice" is a webbrowseable property of the custom webpart.

Please let me know if I am not very much clear about the problem.

P.S I am looking for a solution that doesn't need any code changes in my custom web part.

Many thanks

Vivek

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem. Are you retriving the web part from somewhere using SPLimitedWebPartManager or how do you "access" it?

Comment: Well I am trying to create a page dynamically and adding a custom web part on that page.this is all in the same site.